# Briding LXD Containers to VLAN

Tags: linux, networking, vlan, bridge, lxd

I was trying to do something that is supposed to be pretty easy but for some reason it not work.

I want to bridge two LXD containers to the same VLAN.

To do this I create the VLAN interface over the physical one and then I assign this to the same virtual bridge used by the LXD container.

This is the script that I use for creating the interface and the bridge

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sudo ip link add link $1 name $1.$2 type vlan id $2
sudo ifconfig $1.$2 $3 # this is useless I think

sudo ip link add vnet$2 type bridge

sudo ip link set vnet$2 up
sudo ip link set $1.$2 up

sudo ip link set dev $1.$2 master vnet$2

read -n 1 -s -r -p "Press any key to destroy..."

sudo ip link del vnet$2
sudo ip link del $1.$2
```

And this is the profile used by the containers

```
lxc profile show vlan
config: {}
description: Default LXD profile
devices:
  eth0:
    name: eth0
    nictype: bridged
    parent: vnet2
    type: nic
  root:
    path: /
    pool: default
    type: disk
name: vlan
used_by:
- /1.0/containers/lxd1
```

I assing two ip address in the same subnet for the two containers, but if I try to ping, using tcpdump, I can see that one of the two host is receives the ARP requests and send the replies, while the other one does not receive the replies.

Any suggestion?

This picture represents my testbed

```
   +-------------------------+                 +-------------------------+
   |      Host1              |                 |     Host2               |
   |-------------------------|                 |-------------------------|
   |                         |                 |                         |
   |   +---------+       +----------+   +----------+    +----------+     |
   |   |  ens2.2 +------->   |ens2  <---+ ens2 |   <----+ ens2.2   |     |
   |   +----^----+       +----------+   +----------+    +------^---+     |
   |        |                |                 |               |         |
   |   +----+----+           |                 |        +------+---+     |
   |   | vnet2   |           |                 |        | vnet2    |     |
   |   +---^-----+           |                 |        +------^---+     |
   |       |                 |                 |               |         |
   |       |                 |                 |               |         |
   | +-----+-------------+   |                 |  +------------+-----+   |
   | |  LXD Container    |   |                 |  |  LXD Container   |   |
   | +-------------------+   |                 |  +------------------+   |
   |                         |                 |                         |
   +-------------------------+                 +-------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the LXD and Bridge configuration was Ok, for some reason the switch was not able to manage the VLANs